# Design Patterns used in WPF

Tags: wpf, design-patterns

Following is excrept from [this article](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx) on MVVM. Can someone provide example of how these other patterns (command, DI) are used in WPF? Are there any other desgin patterns that are used in WPF that you don't see listed here ?

> There are other patterns you should be aware of to assist you in MVVM. Patterns like commanding (baked into WPF, solutions for SL), mediator and *gasp* dependency injection. .

Comment: WPF and Silverlight are pretty similar in terms of these things.

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure how your response is related to my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Could you explain why you ask this question?

Comment: While reading the article about these pattern, I just got curious as to what patterns are used in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding (between View and ViewModel) uses the Observer pattern. Also: the Factory pattern can be used to instantiate the ViewModel but that is optional.

Answer (score 29):

I've written the article about some of them: [WPF and Silverlight design patterns](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/wpf-and-silverlight-design-patterns/)

Here is a brief description of the patterns:

1) **MVVM** - used as a model converter and as a replacement of the code-behind. Improves testability, it is much easier to write unit tests for ViewModel.

2) **Dependency Injection** - used for improving testability of a class (you can write unit tests for a specific class separately from others) and for the possibility to change implementation in easier way (change a logger, cache provider, web service etc)

3) **Command** - can be applied to Button and MenuItem controls by default, disables controls if an action can't be executed. Also used in MVVM pattern as a replacement of code-behind events.

Other patterns from the classic book which are already used in WPF:

- Singleton. The Application class in WPF and the HttpContext class
  in Web  forms.
- Adapter. The data-binding engine, which uses the IValueConverter
  interface to  convert binding values for the UI.
- Decorator. The Border class, which decorates any  UIElement class
  with a border of variable thickness and color.
- Façade. The PrintDialog class,  which provides a simple interface
  that enables you to use the entire  printing and document subsystem
  that WPF provides.
- Command. The  ICommand interface, which is implemented by the
  RoutedCommand and  RoutedUICommand classes.
- Iterator. The IEnumerator interface, which many collections and lists
  in the .NET  Framework implement.
- Observer. The INotifyPropertyChanged interface and events.

Answer (score 1):

Setter dependency injection:

When using [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) you have to inject an instance of ViewModel into the View by setting it to the view.DataContext property:

```
var viewModel = new CustomViewModel();
var view = new CustomView();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
```